# To be stand-up(meaning)

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I put the word out to the witnesses against me to be stand-up, that I wasn't going to rat anybody out.

What does the 'to be stand-up' mean here?

Comment: https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=WNRI4PuS9GMC&pg=PT74&lpg=PT74&dq=the+irishman+I+put+the+word+out+to+the+witnesses+against+me+to+be+stand-up,+that+I+wasn%27t+going+to+rat+anybody+out.&source=bl&ots=Yiq4f2mAiy&sig=ACfU3U26NS6hYsdpx-rX3zXels9hpxY5lg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiHncTw0tXnAhWIfXAKHVufAJcQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ

Comment: stand in solidarity with, support

Comment: A stand-up witness is one that can withstand crossexamination, but this doesn't seem to be the sense used here, where it seems to mean "one who gives no evidence".

Comment: See [stand up guy](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Stand%20Up%20Guy) on urban dictinary.  Someone who is loyal and reliable to the cause, in the sense of someone who would 'stand up and be counted'.

Comment: Who is the phrase modifying?  Him or them?

Comment: I take it as modifying them, ie: “the witnesses against me”